# Saint Lucia awarded even without votes

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2014

The [Saint Lucia hat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/saint-lucia) is supposed to be awarded to users who "vote on 12/15". But it was awarded to me on several sites *immediately* at 00:00 UTC on 12/15.

[image: I didn't even visit on 12/15 yet!]

I didn't even visit these sites on 12/15 yet!

Comment: LOL - I just the same hat on 2 of my sites!